# Determining rotation of rectangle features for Data Driven Pages in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data-driven-pages, rotate, rectangle

I am trying to generate a large number of plans using the Data Driven Pages in ArcGIS Desktop.

I have created an index layer comprising a series of rectangle features that correspond to set scales on my layout page (eg 1:100, 1:500, etc).  Due to the odd arrangement of the features I laid out the plans with rectangles that are often rotated.  There wasn't a particular feature that I could use alternatively to create a nice layout using strip or grid tools.

I can see in the data driven page there is an option to include rotation.  However I cannot figure out how to measure the rotation of the rectangle features.

Is there a way to do this automatically in the attribute table, similar to the way you can calculate geometry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this using an Advanced or Standard level license of ArcGIS Desktop you could use the [Calculate Polygon Main Angle](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/cartography-toolbox/calculate-polygon-main-angle.htm) tool which:

> Calculates the dominant angles of input polygon features and assigns
>   the values to a specified field in the feature class.

Use this tool on the same feature class that you are using as the source for the index layer of your Data Driven Pages.